# IndexError after running program multiple times

Tags: python

After running my program that generates passwords multiple times I get an IndexError: list Index out of range. I am not sure what is causing the problem

```
import string
import random

def random_pass(length):
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)
    password = []
    upper_case = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    count = 0
    while count < length:
            random_num = random.randint(0,len(alphabet))
            password.append(alphabet[random_num])
            #Checks to see if first character is a uppercase Letter
            if password[0] not in upper_case:
                first_letter = random.randint(0,len(upper_case))
                password[0] = upper_case[first_letter]
            count += 1
    return ''.join(password)
def welcome():
  print("*****************************************************************")
  print("*****************************************************************")


def main(): 
    try:
        get_length = int(input("Please enter the length of your password "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter numbers only")
        main()
    else:
        print("Your {} character password is {}".format(get_length, random_pass(get_length)))
        restart = input("Do you wish to create another password? y/n")
        password = []
    if restart.lower() == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        exit()
main()
```

Comment: You need to include not only the error message `IndexError: list Index out of range` but also the full traceback into the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint` can generate the *end* value as well; you'd need to use `random.randrange` to generate random numbers in the range that includes the start value and *excludes* the end.

Answer (score 0):

Antti Haapala's answers your question but I see a few things that could be improved in your code. The idea is to make your code clearer.

First of all here's my version of your code:

```
import string
import random

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

def random_pass(length):
    first_character = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    password = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for x in range(length - 1))
    return first_character + password

another_password = True
while another_password:
    try:
        length_requested = int(input("Please enter the length of your password "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter numbers only")
        another_password = True
    else:
        print("Your {} character password is {}".format(length_requested, random_pass(length_requested)))
        restart = input("Do you wish to create another password (Y/N)? ")
        another_password = restart.lower() == 'y'
```

The modifications I made of you code:

- Since `alphabet` is never modified, you don't need to recreate it each time you call `random_pass()`. I have put it in the global scope outside of every functions
- Since you can access a character inside a string the same way you access an element in a list you don't need to create a list with the content of `alphabet` or `string.ascii_uppercase`.
- You don't gain more understanding defining a variable with the same content of `string.ascii_uppercase`
- Instead of choosing a random number that you use to choose a character in `alphabet`, you can directly choose a random character with [`random.choice(alphabet)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice)
- It looks like you have a requirement that the first character of the password has to be an upper case letter. In your code you check this inside your while-loop for each new character but that first character won't change once you set it. So I dragged it outside of this loop.

  - Since your first character is going to chosen inside `string.ascii_uppercase`, I used [`random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice) for it.
- To build the rest of the password, I used a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to choose a random character from `alphabet` and the [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) string method. Since I have already chosen the first character I only need `length - 1` random characters.
- You don't need to define `main()` if all you do is call it later.

  - Even if you define `main()` it's not a good idea to call it recursively because for every new password requested (and every time an invalid input is entered by the user), your code has to create a new small scope environment for this function call and, more importantly, it has to keep of all previous small scope environment. You risk exhausting memory eventually. I have used instead a while-loop.
- `restart.lower() == 'y'` will give a boolean value I have used to change `another_password` which controls whether we continue to ask the user if it wants a new password
- You don't need to call `exit()` unless you want to return an exit code to the environment.

If you have more questions, don't hesitate to ask. And continue experimenting.